# Add text at the end of the line having some SPECIFIC String ksh

Tags: regex, sed, ksh

I want to add specific string at the end on each line that has some Strings and the blank line should stay unaffected.
How can I use the sed command so that the string i require is appened after only selected lines.

Say file name be temp.txt

```
abc "123.cf"
abc
abc "456.cf"
ksh
entry "e123.cf"
```

Now i want to append `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to the end of each line that has .cf" in the end
and need the result to be

```
abc "123.cf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
abc
abc "456.cf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
ksh
entry "e123.cf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I'm using the command:

`sed -e 's:.cf"$:.ccf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &:' -i temp.txt`

Does'nt seem to work. :-(
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/.cf"$/ {$(NF+1) = "> /dev/null 2>&1 &"} 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kent$  sed 's#.cf"$#& > /dev/null 2>\&1 \&#' file
abc "123.cf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
abc
abc "456.cf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
ksh
entry "e123.cf" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

it worked in bash.

Comment: @VikU, the reason is that a `&` in the replacement part of the s/// command is a placeholder for the text that matched the pattern. So `echo foo | sed 's/o/&x/g'` outputs `foxox`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Glenns post:

```
awk '/.cf"$/ {$0=$0FS"> /dev/null 2>&1 &"}8' file
```